`go get` не работает без go.mod
Как побороть данную проблему? Что требуется выполнить?

go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent
directory.
'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.

go: файл go.mod не найден в текущем каталоге или каком-либо родительском каталоге.
'go get' больше не поддерживается вне модуля.
Чтобы собрать и установить команду, используйте 'go install' с версией,
например 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
Для получения дополнительной информации см. https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
или запустите 'go help get' или 'go help install'.
Установлен

go version go1.23.3 linux/amd64

Вопрос. Как правильно выполнить тогда команду?
Например для

go get github.com/primer/primer


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

@aleksandr barakin отредактировала вопрос.

Перейдите в корень вашего проекта и выполните команду
go mod init example.org/some

В результате будет создан go.mod
module example.org/some

go 1.23

После создания go.mod заработают go get, go build, go run, go vet и т.д.
Понятное дело, вмеcто example.org/some можно использовать любую URL-подобную строку, за исключением ключевых слов и встроенных модулей (fmt, reflect и т.д.). Ключевые слова вызовут пробелемы при компиляции, а пересечение с встроенными модулями может привести к крайне странным и неожиданным ошибкам.
